# Player Modal transition like the one in Spotify

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

I'm building a music app and I would like to make a transition like the one Spotify (and other music apps like the new Apple Music) does to present its player, a minimized player which expands an covers the main view (modally?) by dragging it or tapping it.

How can I achieve this? Is there any API or idea on how to do this?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at open-source [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController). It provides similar presentation behaviour much like the Music app.

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of cocoacontrols that might be helpful:

- The first One and I think the most accurate [KNSemiModalViewController](https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController), this one used in the National Geographic app its more or less what you need, you would only need to present a full screen view and remove the background animation if you want.
- [MWWindow](https://github.com/jayztemplier/MWWindow) Another possible solution.
- [MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController)

Now all of this controls dont have the "minimize" function just like spotify, the only one I found with this function is [SLParallaxController](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLParallaxController), but you need to figure out how to change the map and the tableview for the content that you want, or just see how he does the dismiss/minimize animation.